# Managing trailing characters using zsh autoloaded completion

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

I'm trying to create an [autoloaded completion file](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#Autoloaded-files) for zsh. To do so, I've added a `_myprog` file in a folder that is in my fpath.

This file goes roughly like this:

```
#compdef myprog
_myprog () {
    local cmd
    if (( CURRENT > 2)); then
        cmd=${words[2]}
        curcontext="${curcontext%:*:*}:myprog-$cmd"
        (( CURRENT-- ))
        shift words
        case "${cmd}" in
          list|ls)
            _arguments : "--limit[Max depth]" "--folders[Print flat list of folders]"
            _describe -t commands "myprog list" subcommands
          ;;
          insert)
            _arguments : "--force[Overwrite file]" "--append[Append to existing data]"
            _describe -t commands "myprog insert" subcommands
            _myprog_complete_folders
          ;;
        esac
    else
        local -a subcommands
        subcommands=(
          "insert:Insert a new file"
          "list:List existing files"
        )
        _describe -t command 'myprog' subcommands
        _arguments : "--yes[Assume yes]" 
        _myprog_complete_files
    fi
}

_myprog_complete_files () {
    _values 'files' $(myprog ls)
}

_myprog_complete_folders () {
    _values 'folders' $(myprog ls --folders)
}

_myprog
```

So, my program has two scenarios where I want auto-completion:

1. When used without subcommand, I'd like to specify a path in a remote location. This is done by the function `_myprog_complete_files` thanks to the `_value` function. The file list is provided by running `myprog ls`, which prints each remote file on a new line.
2. When inserting a new remote file, I'd like to be able to autocomplete the folders name, which is done in the function `_myprog_complete_folders` using `_value` too, but this time the folder list is generated using `myprog ls --folder` instead, which only prints folders.

So far so good... Excepted that zsh is inserting a space after the folder name when I'm using `<tab><tab>` to have the value list displayed and I'm trying to type the file name after the folder name.

For example:

```
$ myprog insert web<tab><tab><tab>
 -- folders --
web/                          web/foo/                web/bar/
```

is supposed to select `web/foo` and it effectively does so and autocomplete to `myprog insert web/foo/`  but notice the trailing space! So if I'm trying to type directly the name of the file I want to insert once I've selected the folder I wanted using `<tab>`, say I want to call it `baz`, I'm ending up with `myprog insert web/foo/ baz` which is not my goal at all.

I've tried browsing through the zsh doc, without success. 
I've for example tried to set  `zstyle ':completion::complete:myprog-insert:' add-space false` to no avail, both in my .zshrc and in my `_myprog` file. I couldn't even see a difference when having it set or not.

I'm guessing I must be missing something, since it seems to be a desirable feature to be able to type directly after autocompletion in order to specify a parameter or so.

Answer (score 2):

The `add-space` code in `$fpath[-1]/_expand` does not appear to be involved with your completion via `_values`; this can be checked by setting `add-space` to false everywhere, or by calling `_complete_debug` and seeing what code the completion went through:

```
% bindkey -M viins "^t" _complete_debug
% foo 
Trace output left in /tmp/zsh438foo2 (up-history to view)
```

One solution is to use the `-s ...` feature of `_values`, which can optionally insert a separator that is normally used to join multiple values, and then to disable that feature if the separator has been used:

```
#compdef foo
local curcontext="$curcontext" state line

choices=(aaa bbb ccc)

_arguments '1:dir:->folders' && return 0

case "$state" in
  folders)
    if ! compset -P '*/'; then
      _values -s / folders $choices
    fi
  ;;
esac
```

Which on a `foo a`<kbd>tab</kbd> should append a slash, and then since `/` now appears the `compset` test should prevent additional completions.

Comment: While this is effectively not the ideal way to do it, since it keeps trying to complete after typing stuff, it does effectively solve my problem. I tried using `-S` (which didn't work) but didn't try using `-s`, since it refused the empty separator... I should have tried using slashes directly (they were currently in my _values already, so I had to remove the trailing slashes for this method to work.)

Comment: @Lery figured it out, `compset` can look for the `/` and based on that disable completion

Comment: I think I've found  a bug with this compset solution: suppose I have a path like this:
`foo/bar/zen`; `fee/zen/bar`; `fee/foo/bar`; When I type `f` and try to autocomplete with tab, then press enter to select `fee/` and type the first letter of the next subfolder, say `z`, the autocompletion will show "no matches found". It's even worse if I type manually `fee/z` then the autocompletion directly does nothing. I'm guessing it's because of the way compset is modifying the iprefix, maybe, but I'm not sure.

Comment: What I want to do seems very close to what is asked in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42526436/zsh-completion-with-virtual-path it's a shame it remained unanswered. And it seems `_values` is not a solution.
I've also tried specifying -S / and specifying in my values that they accept an argument, but to no avail. When I'm typing we<tab> to get to web/, if I keep typing web/f<tab>, it won't keep completing, no matter what solution I'm trying. Would you happen to have any idea to solve this?

Comment: The SO question linked in the comment above now has an answer, which solve a similar issue I was having. :-)